# printing agruments using text interpreter and execl

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to print command line arguments using execl function which executes a text interpreter but I am not able to get the first argument printed.

this is my main program

```
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>

   int main(int argc,char *argv[])
   {
      pid_t pid;
      if((pid=fork())<0)
          printf("error\n");
      else if(pid==0)
      if((execl("textinterpreter","this","is","usp","lab",(char*)0))<0)
            perror("error in execl\n");

      if(waitpid(pid,NULL,0) !=pid)
          printf("error1\n");
      system("ls > list");
      return 0;
    }
```

This is my textinterpreter file

```
      #!/home/chirag/echoarg1 my1
```

This is my echoarg1.c file

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<unistd.h>
     #include<fcntl.h>
     #include<sys/types.h>
     #include<sys/stat.h>
    main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
           printf("argv[%d]=%s\n",i,argv[i]);
     }
```

The output I am getting is

```
        argv[0]=/home/chirag/echoarg1
        argv[1]=my1
        argv[2]=textinterpreter
        argv[3]=is
        argv[4]=usp
        argv[5]=lab
```

Where as the expected output is

```
        argv[0]=/home/chirag/echoarg1
        argv[1]=my1
        argv[2]=textinterpreter
        argv[3]=this
        argv[4]=is
        argv[5]=usp
        argv[6]=lab
```

Can someone please point out the mistake.

Comment: I would have expected argv[2] to be "this" and "textinterpreter" to have been skipped. The first argument to execp is the _file-path_ which should not be passed in argv. The remaining arguments, up to the NULL pointer, are populated into argv[0]...

Comment: So can you tell why is this happening?

Comment: As I said, my understanding of execp is that the first argument would not be passed into argv of the new program. This does not agree with what you reported where the second argument is not being passed in. Exactly what flavor of Linux/Unix are you using?

Comment: #34~precise1-Ubuntu   3.11.0-20-generic

Comment: It appears that the bash interpreter is using the executable path and not the passed arg0.

Comment: From the bash man page in the section on `#!`:

"The arguments to the interpreter consist of a single optional argument following the  interpreter  name on the first line of the program, followed by the name of the program, followed by the command arguments, if any."

It seems the bash interpreter is what is ignoring arg0 and using the "name of the program" directly.

Comment: @DoxyLover does the bash man snippet help clarify?  Your understanding of execp is correct.  The first argument is not being passed into argv -- it's just that the bash intepreter is ignoring argv[0] and using the file name of the script instead.

Answer (score 0):

from the execl man page:

> int
>   execl(const char *path, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);

and

> The initial argument for these functions is the pathname of a file which
>   is to be executed.
>
> The const char *arg0 and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(),
>   and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.
>   Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated
>   strings that represent the argument list available to the executed program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to the file name
>   associated with the file being executed.  The list of arguments must be
>   terminated by a NULL pointer.

---

so in your line:

```
  if((execl("textinterpreter","this","is","usp","lab",(char*)0))<0)
```

"textinterpreter" is the path of the file to execute, but execl is expecting the next argument, `arg0`, to "point to the file name associated with the file being executed".

in other words it should look more like:

```
  if((execl("textinterpreter","textinterpreter","this","is","usp","lab",(char*)0))<0)
```

Usually the first two args to execl would likely be the same, but it allows you the flexibility to specify one arg for finding the file to execute and another argument to pass as argv[0].

---

As an experiment, try changing your `execl` to call `echoarg1` directly like this:

```
if((execl("echoarg1","FAKEPATH","this","is","usp","lab",(char*)0))<0)
```

You should see output like:

```
argv[0]=FAKEPATH
argv[1]=this
argv[2]=is
argv[3]=usp
argv[4]=lab
```

---

In your example it appears that it's displaying "this" instead of "textinterpreter" as a result of the how the bash interpreter handles your "textinterpreter" script.  The bash interpreter appears to acting as follows:

- takes the hash-bang line and runs `/home/chirag/echoarg1`
- pass it `argv[0]=/home/chirag/echoarg1`
- pass  it the rest of the hashbang line as additional args (in this case just `argv[1]=my1`)
- as it appends the original argv list it appears use the executable path ("textinterpreter") instead of the actual argv[0] ("this") and then   continues with argv[1] ("is") and the rest...

Comment: arg0 is the argument to be made available to the file to be executed. It does not have to point to the file. Your solution will give the output that I want but it does not explain why this is happening.

Comment: It explains it in the man page section.  The first `execl` arg is a path to load and run, but the next arg is what is passed as `argv[0]`.

Comment: The first argument is const char *path. arg0 is to be passed ad argv[0] according to man page.

Comment: Yeah, if you do the "experiment" above it will work directly as the man page suggests.  The switch appears to be happening due to the bash interpreter.

Comment: `execl` is doing the correct thing here.  Usually the first two arguments to `execl` will be the same.  But as the man page for `execl` points out in the snippet above, this is *by convention*.  `execl` does not force you to pass the same value for `path` and `arg0`.  In your example you'll want to pass "textinterpreter" for both.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is not *the bash interpreter* (whatever that's supposed to mean - there is no `bash` involved here) which discards `arg0`, but it is the kernel's function [`load_script()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_script.c#L79) with the statement

```
         retval = remove_arg_zero(bprm);
```

above it there is a comment saying

```
          * Splice in (1) the interpreter's name for argv[0]
          *           (2) (optional) argument to interpreter
          *           (3) filename of shell script (replace argv[0])
```

- in your case, (1) `/home/chirag/echoarg1`, (2) `my1`, (3) `textinterpreter` (replace `this`).